# How to place a banner in my profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, hyperlinks, flair

Am I allowed to place a banner of a website in Stack Exchange profile? If yes, I tried to see how it looks (I didn't save my profile, so the permission is really needed!) but nothing happened. It's an embed code and the banner size is 125x125 (width x height).

---

[Permission has been given]

The following is the above mentioned code:

```
<a href="http://www.onehourtranslation.com/affiliate/gigili">
    <img src="http://static.onehourtranslation.com/images/banners/set2/translation-services-125x125.jpg" alt="professional translation" border="0">
</a>
```

Comment: what is the code that you used?

Comment: @MattDMo Umm, since it's basically advertising a website I thought it'd be a bad idea to put it here as well as my profile! Is it needed?

Comment: @Gigili I think you can do anything with your own profile (avertise your own products etc) as long as it can't be considered evil (logging IPs, installing malware etc) or highly likely to offend

Comment: @RichardTingle Well then, but why it does not work?

Comment: @Gigli: Well then, since you didn't show what you did, it's hard to say. "I won't show you what I did, but it doesn't work" as a StackOverflow question gets downvoted and closed pretty quickly.

Comment: The code is the following except in the original version the website address is quite diffrent: <a href="http://www.XXX.com"><img src="http://XXX.com/images/banners/set2/translation-services-125x125.jpg" alt="professional translation" border="0"></a>

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not afraid of downvotes and closevotes. (I'm a brave man!) But I wasn't sure it was a good idea. The only thing I'm thinking about is to place that banner in my profile, that'd be my final goal.

Comment: I wasn't talking about you getting downvotes. I was talking about the poor quality of saying "Here's no information about what I tried. It doesn't work. Why? And how do I fix it?". Again, that bad question on SO would be closed very quickly, for a very good reason.

Comment: Also, if you can't tell me what's wrong without knowing what I ave done, then when exactly you use your magic powers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Just use the regular markdown syntax. It seems like full HTML has been giving you trouble.

Possibly it was the alt attribute, or the unnecessary use of border="0" (not like it'd have a border anyway).

#### For an image

```
![image alt text, optional but encouraged](http://www.example.com/image.png)
```

or

```
![image alt text, optional but encouraged][1]

[1]: http://www.example.com/image.png "This is the image title, it's optional"
```

#### For a link

```
[the link content](http://www.example.com/)
```

or

```
[the link content][1]

[1]: http://www.example.com "Same again"
```

#### Putting it together

```
[![Example dot com, the hippest site in the sector][image]][site]

[image]: http://www.example.com/image.png
[site]: http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: Yes, it had something to do with the border. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes.

Just don't be creepy and hotlink it to your server and log our IP's ;)

Comment: Good idea, I'm on it!